# Redux - Throttle an action so not fired so often

Tags: react-redux

I have an action creator that fires an action anytime a button key is pressed, however it fires too often especially when a user is typing in a field. In regular react you can use lodash and throttle or debounce that, is there a way to do this with Redux and the way it dispatches actions to throttle it?

I found one article on it https://medium.com/@leonardobrunolima/react-tips-how-to-create-a-redux-middleware-throttle-f2908ee6f49e but that did not work out for me, maybe I copied that example too literally any other examples or resources on this topic? I cannot find anything and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the use case? Can you post some code and explain the context behind the problem?

Comment: why wouldn't lodash throttle on the event handler work in this case? should be the exact same thing, with or without redux

Comment: It is a very large code base, but basically, there are functions to detect mouse events like scrolling or typing a key to detect activity, called lastActivityUpdate(), so that way the session timeout does not kick in, but when you scroll, it fires off like 30 action events, would be nice to throttle or debounce every 2000 ms or so.

Comment: Why not try to  throttle submitting actions on the event handler itself and not mix this feature into redux ? I don't see this usecase to be handled as part of redux

Comment: Thank you guys, that was the best way to do this! I decided to use lodash and literally like you all suggested went with _.throttle or _.debounce on the event handler and that seems to have done the trick, now I don't have to mess with the reducer at all!